# Flat file line number via ODI 12c

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I have a need which consists of importing data from flat file into an Oracle table via ODI 12c.

Lines are filtered according to some condition (business rules), only those satisfying the rules are integrated into the destination table. Others go to an error file which should specify the line number in the original file and the rule/condition which wasn't fulfilled.

So my question is, how can I get the line number from the original file?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show some code you tried...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Marcus did not find much code on this problem, but I have tried ROWNUM directly in the destination column but it seems that ROWNUM get the row number in the destination table not the line number in the original file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the odi sequence to track the each record row number . Records reported to error table will be having the sequence number associated with it. After each load you need to set the sequence to 1 so it should start with 1 with each load.